# Mostrar JSON con API desde Angular 4

Tags: javascript, json, angular, rest, get

Trato de mostrar mi Objeto desde un servicio GET pero únicamente puedo ver [Object][object].

Service:

```
return this.http.get('http://localhost:3000/words').map((res: Response) => res.json());
```

Controller:

```
export class WordsComponent implements OnInit {
  words: Word[];
  private _productService;

    constructor(servicio : WordsService, public http: HttpClient) {
      this._productService = servicio;
      this.words = this._productService.getWords();

      console.log("Ver words " + JSON.stringify(this._productService.getWords()));


    }

     ngOnInit(): void {}
```

JSON:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "test",
    "translate": "prueba",
    "created_at": "2018-06-10T21:15:06.000Z",
    "updated_at": "2018-06-10T21:15:06.000Z"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "test-one",
    "translate": "prueba-uno",
    "created_at": "2018-06-10T21:15:22.000Z",
    "updated_at": "2018-06-10T21:15:22.000Z"
  }]
```

Answer (score 1):

Estás confundiendo conceptos:

```
this.words = this._productService.getWords();
```

El atributo words no guarda el resultado de la llamada AJAX, sino un observable. Tienes que suscribirte al observable para obtener el resultado:

```
this.words : Observable<Words[]> = this._productService.getWords();
this.words.subscribe(data: Words[] => {
  console.log("Ver words " + JSON.stringify(data));
  //llamar a funciones que trabajen con los datos
}
```